# If $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, what is $\frac{dx}{dr}$ and $\frac{dr}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus

If $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, what is $\frac{dx}{dr}$ and $\frac{dr}{dx}$  ?

Comment: $\frac{dr}{dx}=\frac{d(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{dx} = \frac{x}{r}$
$\frac{dx}{dr}=\frac{d(r\cos{\theta})}{dr} = \frac{x}{r}$
I think one of them is wrong, but I don't know why it is wrong.

Comment: They are both correct, assuming that you mean $\partial r/\partial x$ (with $y$ kept fixed) and $\partial x/\partial r$ (with $\theta$ kept fixed). It's not true for partial derivatives that $\partial r/\partial x = 1/(\partial x/\partial r)$. What's true is that the whole Jacobian matrix $\partial (r,\theta)/\partial (x,y)$ is the inverse matrix of $\partial (x,y)/\partial (r,\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos \theta\implies \frac{dx}{dr}=\cos \theta$$

$$r=\frac x{\cos \theta}\implies \frac{dr}{dx}=\frac1{\cos\theta}$$

Comment: What if I am not using polar coordinates?
$\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{d\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{dx} = \frac{x}{r}$ ?

Comment: In any case, we should make sure whether there's no hidden or open relation between the different variables. For example, I wrote that $\;\frac{dx}{dr}=\cos\theta\;$ **assuming** $\;\theta\;$ is *not* a function of $\;r\;$ . If it were then things get more interesting. If we're talking of polar coordinates then we usually have that there're no extra relations between the variables.

Comment: If we're working with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ together with Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$, $\partial r/\partial x$ usually means that $y$ should be kept fixed while differentiating $r$, not that $\theta$ should be kept fixed. If that's what is meant, your second equality is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
 r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} &\Leftrightarrow {} r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \\[2mm]
 &\Leftrightarrow \Big( \frac{x}{r} \Big)^{2} + \Big( \frac{y}{r} \Big)^{2} = 1 \\[2mm]
 &\Leftrightarrow \exists \theta \in [0,2\pi[, \, \displaystyle \frac{x}{r} = \cos(\theta) \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \frac{y}{r} = \sin(\theta). \\
\end{align*}
$$

As a consequence : $\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}$.

Comment: Can I directly compute $\frac{dr}{dx}$ in the following way?
$\frac{dr}{dx}$ = $\frac{d(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{dx}=\frac{x}{r}$

In this case $\frac{dr}{dx}$ = $\frac{dx}{dr}$ ?

Comment: @KelvinChan1008 : Yes, you can say that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined! It follows that

$$ \mathrm{d}r = (x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} (x\, \mathrm{d}x + y \, \mathrm{d}y ) $$

but you've given no reason to believe that $\mathrm{d} r$ and $\mathrm{d} x$ are proportional to one another.

If we were doing, for example a calculation where $\mathrm{d}r = 0$, then we would have

$$ 0 = (x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2} (x\, \mathrm{d}x + y \, \mathrm{d}y ) $$

and thus in the domain where $x^2 + y^2 > 0$ we could thus conclude

$$ x\, \mathrm{d} x = - y\, \mathrm{d} y $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{x}{y} \qquad \text{where } y \neq 0$$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = -\frac{y}{x} \qquad \text{where } x \neq 0$$

(and, for example, the last equation above this is the same result you'd get if you solved the original equation for $x$ as a function of of $y$ then took the derivative of said function)

but in general, when you have three independent variables, it is very rare that the differential of two of the variables (say, $u$ and $v$) are proportional, and thus writing $\mathrm{d}u / \mathrm{d}v$ is nonsensical.

---

If you intended to ask about *partial derivatives*: e.g. $\partial y/\partial x$, then you have to know how you're supposed to be taking the derivative: the notation is inherently ambiguous, but e.g. having $\mathrm{d}r = 0$ is typically implied when you have an equation involving $x,y,r$ and someone asks for $\partial y/\partial x$.

In that case, the value of $\partial y/\partial x$ is the same as the value of $\mathrm{d}y / \mathrm{d}x$ we'd get if we set $\mathrm{d}r = 0$ like I did above.

Comment: I am sorry, I want to ask $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ actually

Answer (score 0):

Given only that $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and assuming that $y$ is independent of $x$ (which is very safe given this looks like coordinate transformation), then
$$
\begin{aligned}
r = \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\[1ex]
dr=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2x \mathrm{d}x \\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{x}{r}
\end{aligned}
$$
And, $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}r}$ is left to the OP to do by inspection.